# Configuring ssh access for a resource manager template

Tags: powershell, azure, ssh, azure-resource-manager

Every Linux VM I create either in the Azure web portal or using Powershell in Windows and using the ARM (Azure Resource Manager), doesn't seem to have a proper private IP address, i.e. 10.1.1.14 or similar. Which doesn't seem to allow me SSH access and I suppose why would it?

How does one configure SSH access and in particular the private IP address whilst using the ARM in the portal? Or even better using powershell to fire a local .json template at my Azure subscription?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created the Linux VM and the Virtual Network with that, and it says the 10.0.1.4 private IP. I think that you do not need that private IP for setting the access, you need to set the endpoint for the virtual network and, for example, public ip.

For that, i would refer to the [Azure ARM Quickstart gallery](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-sshkey) sample which creates the VM as i understand you need it to be. There are a lot of different samples you could use, but i believe the link above implements what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will have a look at that and see if I can alter the template to suit my needs. I think now that in a resource group, one has to use SSH keys??

Comment: @user2786484 yes, please try it and tell if that is working for you. Yes for the second

Comment: I think you are right on this one but there is something fundamental that I do not understand as I still cant get SSH access. I have deployed it and now I assume that I need to use putty to connect to it.  I created I key using putty geygen and pasted in the public key in to the keyfile field on deployment in Azure. So now how do I use the private side of the key to access my VM via SSH using Putty. I assume one tries to connect to the Public IP as endpoints are created with this deployment template. Thanks